# Deserializing JSON string into string array

Tags: c#, json

I'm somehow having troubles deserializing a json string into a simple List or string[] (I don't care which).

As of what I know, this is how to do this job:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(jsonString);
```

Here I am getting a RuntimeBinderException. It complains about the parameter, although my json string is valid and simple: `a:1:{i:0;s:10:"Sahibinden";}`

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid. Paste it into http://json2csharp.com. If you haven't given us the full string, please do so.

Comment: Your JSON is also not an array, so it cannot be deserialized into a list.

Comment: I didn't know there were different json syntaxs between programming languages. Here it worked: http://www.unserialize.com/s/06402092-abe2-3969-82f4-0000513f719e
Thanks guys, I will do some research.

Comment: There `are not` different JSON syntax between programming languages. There `are` different serialization syntax between them. A serialized object is not a JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

What you have isn't JSON is a serialized PHP object. There have been some tools that work well with this in C# but there isn't native support. If you own the PHP, then convert the object/array to JSON first. If not try the information on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1923626/474702

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid. Problems:

1. a:1 should be inside an object bracket of {}
2. The : before the { is invalid, you need a , there
3. The ; just after i:0 is invalid, you need a comma there
4. You repeat the mistake described in 1. and 2. inside your {} brackets as well

Solution: You need to read about JSON and make sure you understand its syntax.